# Heisenberg's microscope and gravity

Tags: gravity, metric-tensor, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-gravity

Is the Heisenberg's microscope gedanken experiment valid when considering spacetime kinematics?

That is, if we consider a small region of space and try to measure its curvature, then we may use photons and see how the trajectory changes. On the other hand, the photon's energy changes the very curvature that we are about to measure. Here I assume that a high energy photon "maps" curvature more accurately. The ultimate goal would be to find an uncertainty principle that connects curvature and the rate at which the curvature changes.

Comment: I suggest looking into *generalized uncertainty principle* (GUP) governing all measurement processes in quantum gravity. See e.g. [Maggiore](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9301067) for a model-independent derivation and [Tawfik&Diab](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0206) for a review.

Comment: @A.V.S. My question is not about the QM uncertainty principle at the Planck scale.